# Why can't I call a protected method from an inheriting class in another package in Java?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, attributes

Say there's the following base class:

```
package bg.svetlin.ui.controls;

public abstract class Control {
    protected int getHeight() {
        //..
    }
    //...
}
```

Also, in the same package, there's a class that inherits:

```
package bg.svetlin.ui.controls;

public abstract class LayoutControl extends Control {
    public abstract void addControl(Control control);
    //...
}
```

Then, there's a third class in another package:

```
package bg.svetlin.ui.controls.screen;

public abstract class Screen extends LayoutControl {
    //...
}
```

And, finally, there's the implementation class, again in a different package:

```
package bg.svetlin.ui.controls.screen.list;    

public class List extends Screen {

    private final Vector controls = new Vector();

    public void addControl(Control control) {
        height += control.getHeight();
        controls.addElement(control);
    }
}
```

Even though `List` inherits from `Control`, and the `getHeight()` is `protected`, there's the following error:

> getHeight() has protected access in bg.svetlin.ui.controls.Control

I've checked that my imports are right. I'm using NetBeans.

Any idea what's wrong? I thought `protected` fields and methods are visible to the children even if the latter are in a different package.

Thanks!

Comment: In your abstract class the method is `getWidth()`, in the subclass you're using `getHeight()`. Is this just because it's example code?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for spotting this out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I thought protected fields and methods are
>   visible to the children even if the latter are in a different package.

That's correct. The class itself has an access to the inherited protected members. But, what you're trying to do it to call the `getHeight` method on *some* Control reference. You're allowed to call it only on **this** instance!

For a better understanding, let me quote Kathy Sierra's [SCJP Preparation Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071591060):

> But what does it mean for a subclass-outside-the-package to have
>   access to a superclass (parent) member? It means the subclass inherits
>   the member. It does not, however, mean the
>   subclass-outside-the-package can access the member using a reference
>   to an instance of the superclass. In other words, protected =
>   inheritance. **The subclass can see the protected member
>   only through inheritance**.

Comment: How could I make a method available only to a class and it's sub-classes, then? Thanks!

Comment: Like I said, it **is** available to your subclass. But you only allowed to call it on **this** reference, such as `this.getHeight()` (*this* is optional of course). It's a common practice though, to make an accessor method **public**.

Comment: The dimensions and the positions would be held automatically by my library, so I wanted to leave them private to the library. It looks like I'll have to make them public then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're right. Any `protected` member or `method` accessible from children class, but you want access to protected method of a parameter instance in `addControl` method. You can access only to `protected`  method of `List` class (`this.getHeight()`)