# How to keep a clean Java API

Tags: java

I'm trying to design a Java API roughly like this:

```
package core;

public abstract class GraphNode {
    public void add(Condition... conditions) {
        // check conditions isn't null, and translate them into a Map

        this.addCore(translatedConditions, new TraversalContext());
    }

    protected abstract void addCore(Map<String, Condition> conditions, TraversalContext traversalContext);
}
```

The problem is that I need my concrete implementations to be able to recursively pass control onto subsequent nodes in the graph. Something like this:

```
package core.nodes;

public final class ConcreteGraphNode extends GraphNode {
    @Override
    protected void addCore(Map<String, Condition> conditions, TraversalContext traversalContext) {
        if (conditions.size() == 0) {
            // recursion done
            return;
        }

        // remove the appropriate condition, modify the traversal context, create or find the next node in the graph

        // pass the call on recursively
        nextNode.addCore(conditions, traversalContext);
    }

}
```

My motivation here is threefold:

1. Incur the cost of argument checking only once when called via the public API. Thenceforth, all recursion happens against non-public APIs, so the argument validation can be skipped (or just asserted).
2. Enable the non-public API to take an extra context parameter that has no business being in the public API because it's an implementation detail.
3. Include only the minimal abstraction types in the `core` package, with a separate package (`core.nodes`) for actual implementations of those abstractions.

However, Java's accessibility modifiers don't seem to accommodate this. By being in a separate package, I can no longer call `protected` members declared by my superclass. In other words, the call to `nextNode.addCore` in the `ConcreteGraphNode` is not possible.

I'm wondering whether there's some elegant way around this that doesn't require me to move my implementation classes into my `core` package?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow... If `ConcreteGraphNode extends GraphNode`, shouldn't all of `GraphNode`'s `protected` members be visible within `ConcreteGraphNode` no matter what package `ConcreteGraphNode` is? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @user3580294: no, that's not how it works in Java because I'm trying to call the protected member on another instance, not against `this`. See here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9546279/5380

Comment: Ah, you're right. That was rather dumb of me. I apologize for my mistake.